# How can I filter inappropriate youtube videos?

Tags: filter, youtube, filtering

I am developing an application that runs completely unattended and displays some info on fixed monitors (like in an hotel hall). I'm planning to allow users to submit videos using a web site, and those videos will be displayed every day at a certain time.

As this program is completely unattended (no moderation desired), it should automatically filter inappropriate videos (sexual, violence, etc)...

So, the questions are:

Is YouTube filter automatic or does it need X users seeing the video and marking it as inappropriate?

How much time does it take to detect that its inappropriate?

Thanks to anybody that can give me ANY piece of information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is dependend on users flagging a video. I really wouldn't do it the way you are proposing, simply because there will be videos slipping through the net you are putting up; and I don't think you want to allow that.

Comment: Ok, I see... But just to dig a bit, did you mean that youtube has no automatic filter or that it is not flawless?

Comment: Youtube doesn't have a filter that I'm aware of, at least not for your target content. Even if it had such a filter, there still could be false negatives, and that wouldn't be good for your usage.